# ios - UIWebView DidFinishLoad not being called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a `UIWebView` that works ok. The delegate is working. When I open a URL, events `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` are fired.

But when for example I click on a Google search result, only `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is fired, and `webViewDidFinishLoad` is never called.

This is causing problems because if I put a "loading..." indicator on `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`, in these cases the indicator still remains even after the page is correctly loaded.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: set delegate to your webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert on Google API, but as I suspected this might be your [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568661/why-are-google-search-results-in-uiwebview-not-triggering-webviewdidfinishload).

Answer (score 1):

in .h file add `<UIWebViewDelegate>`

and in .m:

```
yourWebview=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
yourWebview.delegate=self;
```

Comment: @Thedude:I know that. But he haven't posted any code .So I can only guess the possibilities . And above seems to be best possibility .

Answer (score 1):

When you click on search, the navigationType is UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted. So in this case, the return type should be YES. If it is not, webViewDidFinishLoad method is not fired.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest");

    if ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ){
        NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked");

        return YES;
    } 
    if (navigationType ==UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted ) {
        NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted");
        return YES;
    }
    if (navigationType ==UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward) {
        NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeBackForward");
        return YES;
    }
    if (navigationType ==UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormResubmitted) {
        NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormResubmitted");
        return YES;
    }
    if (navigationType ==UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload) {
        NSLog(@"UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload");
        return YES;
    }



    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is usually found on ipad applications .... but you can solve your problem by using [self performselector:afterdelay] , you have to check in selector method whether webview has loaded or not using [m_pWebview loaded]; and according to that perform indicator stopping .... it's not the proper solution but it works .......